# Construct the dfa for language L = (a*b*) | (ab)*

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

Construct a DFA for the given language.

```
L = (a*b*) | (ab)*
```

Answer (score 1):

That one should do:

```
(start & final) ----------------- b ---------------\              
       |                                           |
       a              /- a -\           /- b -\    |          
       |              |     |           |     |    |
       v              v     |           v     |    |
    (final) --- a --> (final) --- b --> (final) <--/
       |                                 ^   |
       b                                 |   |
       |                                 |   | 
       v                                 |   |
    (final) ------------- b -------------/   |
     |                                       |
     a   /--------------- a -------------\   a
     |   |                               |   | 
     v   |                               v   v
    (state) --- b --> (final) --- b --> (error)
       ^                 |
       \------- a -------/
```